# vuejs2 adding event listener to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I have a **replies** component and **newReply** component in my page. When a newReply is added, i emit an event on a global vue message bus to notify the **replies** component that a new reply has been added so that it reloads and re-renders.

```
methods: {
  updateReplyList: function(newReply){
          window.vueMessageBus.$emit('notifyingrepliescomponent',newReply);
        },
}
```

i have attached the event listener for the **notifyingrepliescomponent** event inside the created() hook of **replies** component.

**UPDATED CODE SNIPPET**

```
//file: replies.vue

methods: {

        fetch: function(url = null){
            let vm = this;

            if(!url)
            {
                axios.get(route('replies.paginated',{ 'thread' : this.thread_id }))
                .then(function(serverResponse){
                    vm.replies_with_pagination = serverResponse.data;           
 //'replies_with_pagination' holds the paginated collection returned by laravel for the current paginated page
                });                                                             

          }                                                                 

         else
            {
              var page = url.match(/\?page=(\d+)/i)[1];
              axios.get(route('replies.paginated',{ 'thread' : this.thread_id, 'page' : page }))
               .then(function(serverResponse){
                    vm.replies_with_pagination = serverResponse.data; 
                });     
            }                                                                


        },

        reloadNew: function(url){
            this.fetch(url);
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
        },
    },

created() {
        this.fetch();

        window.vueMessageBus.$on('notifyingrepliescomponent',newReply => {
           console.log('added object: ' + newReply);
           this.all_reply_items.push(newReply);

           this.reloadNew(route('replies.paginated',{ 'thread' : this.thread_id, 'page' : this.pageForQueryString }));

           this.$emit('repliescountchanged',this.all_reply_items.length);
        });        
    },
```

The whole system works, except for the first time. That is when there are no replies to a thread, and i add a new reply, the replies component does not reload. But for the subsequent replies, this works fine.

I am guessing this is an issue with my event listener? Can anyone please help?

TIA, Yeasir

Comment: You say `the replies component does not reload` but does the **notifyingrepliescomponent** event trigger? I.e, do you see the console logs the first time when it has nothing in it?

Comment: yes. In the vue events console i can see the event fires!

Comment: @YeasirArafatMajumder For what purpose do you use window object here?

Comment: If the event fires then you're showing the wrong bit of code. The code that needs examining is the bit that does the reloading (the bit that isn't working for the first time)...

@divine He's using it as a [global event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/) but being lazy by adding it to window to access ;)

Comment: @webnoob: Hi, i have added the code that does the loading of the data and rendering.

Comment: And does any data come back from the server for that initial load that isn't working? You really need to do some basic debugging on this and give us more information. Find out which but is causing the problems then report back.

Comment: Why people use event busses for stuff like this is beyond me. You have shared state, so don't use events to send it around, use a state management solution to manage that state globally.

I know this comment isn't an immediate solution to your problem, but your problem is likely a maniifestation of the usual problem with event busses: Trying to manage something permanent (state) with something volatile (events) between distant components with no way to guarantee that the reciever is even active at the right time.

Comment: @webnoob: I have tried to find the problem from my side. This much i can tell that the event is not being caught by this component(during the first time). You see that **console.log('added object: ')** part - that is not executed. But a new reply is created for sure, and the event is fired too. Now i dont know if i should attach the event handler to a different hook or something else, i am at loss.

Comment: @LinusBorg: Will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: @webnoob I found the issue. It was a problem at the blade side. The replies component was not being created as some condition check failed. So the event handler was not attached to it. Thanks a lot for your time.